# How to make same types with different behavior in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, graph

I use Haskell and Functional Graph Library to represents graphs. There are two ways to compare graphs, directly, over function *equal*, or over another function, i wrote, *isIsomorph*. 
I want to use [hash map](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/unordered-containers/0.2.1.0/doc/html/Data-HashMap-Strict.html) to collect graphs. To do so I have to create instance of class **Eq** for my graphs. But I need two hash maps, first for graphs that compared by function *equal*, and second for graphs that compated by function *isIsomorph*.

---

If I do

```
type Fragment = Gr Atom Bond {-- Gr is a type constructor from the Functional Graph Library}

    instance Eq (Gr Atom Bond) where    
        g == g1 = equal g g1

    instance Eq Fragment where  
        g == g1 = isIsomorph g g1
```

I have got an expected error

```
Duplicate instance declarations:
      instance [overlap ok] Eq (Gr Atom Bond) -- Defined at HLab.hs:45:10
      instance [overlap ok] Eq Fragment -- Defined at HLab.hs:48:10
```

Because of *type* decalration is only wrap.

I can use another way

```
data Fragment = Fragment {fgraph :: Gr Atom Bond}

instance Eq (Gr Atom Bond) where    
    g == g1 = equal g g1

instance Eq Fragment where  
    Fragment g ==  Fragment g1 = isIsomorph g g1
```

That is correct but I have used an "heavy" type constructor *data*, this way is also inconvenient, I have to got graphs from fragments by addtional function fgraph.

Is there any "beautiful" and "true" way to divide this types in various parts of code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "beautiful" and "true" way to divide this types in various parts of code? is to use `newtype` instead of `data`: For all type system purposes, they are different (in particular, you can define different type class instances), but they share the same run-time representation and there is no additional like with `data`:

```
newtype Fragment = Fragment {fgraph :: Gr Atom Bond}

instance Eq (Gr Atom Bond) where    
    g == g1 = equal g g1

instance Eq Fragment where  
    Fragment g == Fragment g1 = isIsomorph g g1
```

You will still need to convert between graphs and fragments when trying to use graph functions on fragments.

Comment: This is the method used by the designers of the GHC Prelude. For example we have two `Monad` instances of [], one of them can be accessed by wrapping the list into `ZipList`

Comment: There are lots of examples of newtype wrappers used to define different instances of algebraic structures. Off the top of my head, `All`, `Any`, `Sum`, `Product`, `First`, `Last`, `Endo`. And these are just for `Monoid`!